# Find out implementation type of input interface

Tags: java, interface, temporary, implements

I have a function which has the interface `Comparable` as input parameter.

```
int sort(Comparable A[]){...}
```

Now I want to make a temporary variable of that type of which `A` is at run time (might be `Integer` or `Float`, but I don't know), to do comparisons for my sorting algorithm.
How is it done? I'm a freshman to Java.

Comment: Please don't use raw types. If you don't know what they are then Google them.

Comment: Why would you have to do that?  Just store it in a `Comparable` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please don't use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Second, I don't think you can but you *could* make a temporary variable of `Comparable`. Something like,

```
static <T> void sort(Comparable<T> A[]){
    if (A == null || A.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Comparable<T> temp = A[0];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you. I'm experiencing a problem: Doing this, I can not access the variable `A` by `A[j-1].compareTo(A[j])`. It gives the compiler error `actual argument Comparable<T#1> cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion`

Comment: Got it. Casted it to `T` by using `A[j-1].compareTo((T)A[j])` and `    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above the method.

Comment: @Clawish that's because your method declaration is all wrong, it should be `static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a)`.